# Side by side form fields with Laravel and Former?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm using [Former](https://github.com/Anahkiasen/former) with Laravel to build a form, and I'm trying to get two fields to be next to each other (in this case, first and last name) and then an email field below it. I've tried adding using `Former::col_md_6_text`, and adding `->addClass('col-md-6')` and neither seemed to do much of anything. Below is the code I'm using in the form:

```
{{  Former::text('first_name')
    ->label("First Name")
    ->placeholder('First Name')
    ->required();
}}

{{  Former::text('last_name')
    ->label("First Name")
    ->placeholder('Last Name')
    ->required();
}}

{{  Former::text('email')
    ->label("Your Email")
    ->placeholder('Your Email')
    ->required();
}}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I've done it in the past - I dont think Former could wrap the field in another div

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    {{  Former::text('first_name')
        ->label("First Name")
        ->placeholder('First Name')
        ->required();
    }}
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    {{  Former::text('last_name')
        ->label("First Name")
        ->placeholder('Last Name')
        ->required();
    }}
</div>
```

[There is an open github issue on this exact thing.](https://github.com/Anahkiasen/former/issues/205) There are some workarounds in there - but at the moment doesnt seem to be a natual option.

Comment: I was afraid this was going to be the answer. Seems like something that should be built in. Thanks.